# My touch screen doesn't work on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, touchscreen

I installed Xubuntu (14.04) on a Sam4s machine. It used to have windows xp, but now the touch screen doesn't work.

How can I fix it? Is there anyway i could possibly just use any kind of touchscreen driver? and witch ones?

Comment: "witch" should be "which" so that online translation services can work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to contact the sam4s support and they sent me a package for my touchscreen.
(SW602130_Elo_Linux_Serial_Driver_v3.3.2_i686.tgz)

I did encounter many problems and figured out that although my processor was 64 bit, the rest of my machine was 32 bit.

I installed the 32 bit xubuntu system, then I completed compiling the driver and had to figure out which serial port worked and responded to this (ended up being /dev/ttyS1).

To see your serial ports use the cmd: `dmesg | grep tty`.
After that, to test it use: `ls > /dev/ttySX (x number)`
After you figure out which serial port works, you have to go into /etc/rc.local and put this message in:

```
/etc/opt/elo/loadelo  
/etc/opt/elo/eloser <PORTNAME1> <PORTNAME2>
```

The `<PORTNAME>` should be the `ttySX` you got.
Example: `/etc/opt/eloser ttyS1`

Then save it. After that, you do `sudo shutdown -r now` and that should be it. Then you calibrate it.

At least mine came with these instructions.